# Simplest way to filter text copied from a web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I have a web page where the text has `&shy;` characters (= soft hyphens) and other unusual entities mixed in. While these entities are necessary for correct display of the page, I would like to filter them out of text copied from the page to the clipboard.

1) Is this possible with JavaScript? I’m familiar with the `onCopy` event, but the examples I’ve seen don’t make the copied text available for further processing.

2) If so, what is the simplest way to accomplish it?

What I can’t do:

a) Change the characters in the web page at the server side.

b) Install JQuery or another JS framework just for this one function.

Comment: javascript doesn't have access to the clipboard, afaik. you'd have to use flash or a similar plugin.

Comment: What are you doing with text after you copy it?

Comment: @JedSchneider: that is not entirely true. Most major browsers support the [`clipboardData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) property in **read-only**. However IE>5 *also* supports the `setData` method (so in IE there was no need for the hidden div/pre work-around).

Comment: @GitaarLAB that's interesting. I know that sites like github still use flash for copying urls to the clipboard, I wasn't aware it was in browsers now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a while, I thought that it was impossible to do it with JS only, but you can! You need to use the `oncopy` event handler, and change the selection to a temporary div containing the filtered text.

Here is an example:

```
function copyHandler() {
    //Get the selected text
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
        // Filter it
        newText = filterText( selection ),
        // Create a div
        newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    // Hide it
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    // Insert the div in the body
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    // Put the text in it
    newdiv.innerHTML = newText;
    // Select what's in the div
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

    // When the copy is over, remove the temporary div
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 100);
}

document.addEventListener('copy', copyHandler);


function filterText(txt){
    /* Do whatever you want here */
    /* To show that it's working, I'll just return that string every time */
    return 'I\'m a filtered String!';
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Try copy / pasting text in the Fiddle.